# how to retrieve last Week,  previous month records from mysql table

Tags: mysql

I have a table which is shown in picture

[image: mySql Table]

I want to retrieve this information.

1) From this date(whatever it is) previous month total 'page_views' of all ip's

2)  Today's 'page_views' grouped by 'page' (expample: id=7 have page =index.php having page_views =12 But in the same date id=13 have same page = index.php and page_views = 1) So they must show page_view of index.php = 13

Comment: It's not look like a question, it looks like "do it for me"

Comment: try http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: i new to mysql. i can retrieve yesterday's record, and todays but not all which i need badly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below query to get the date one month before the specific date.

```
select date_sub(current_date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) .
```

Answer (score 0):

- 1)

  ```
  SELECT SUM(page_views)
  FROM tbl
  WHERE date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
  ```
- 2)

  ```
  SELECT page, SUM(page_views)
  FROM tbl
  WHERE LEFT(date, 10) = CURDATE()
  GROUP BY page
  ```

Comment: **Please Answer the Second Query**

Comment: @A.RehmanJaved, that's weird. The query should have worked. Try the updated solution.

Comment: @A.RehmanJaved, are you sure you even have pageviews for today? You can try adding `CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY` to get yesterday's pageviews and see if anything shows up.